# WebGL shader z position not used in depth calculations

Tags: webgl, depth-buffer, zbuffer

I've been trying out some WebGL but there's a bug I cannot seem to find out how to fix.

Currently I have the following setup:
I have around 100 triangles which all have a position and are being drawn by a single `gl.drawArrays` function. To have them drawn in the correct order I used `gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);` which gave the correct result.

The problem I have now is that if I update the `gl_Position` of the triangles in the vertex shader the updated Z value is not being used in the depth test. The result is that a triangle with a `gl_Position.z` of 1 can be drawn on top of a triangle with a `gl_Position.z` of 10, which is not exactly what I want..

**What have I tried?**

```
gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
gl.depthFunc(gl.GEQUAL);
```

with

```
gl.clear(gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
gl.clearDepth(0);
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, verticesCount);
```

in the render function.

The following code is used to create the buffer:

```
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, dataBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBufferData, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
const positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'position');
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, false, 0, 0);
```

The triangles with a higher z value are much bigger in size (due to the perspective) but small triangles still appear over it (due to the render order).

In the fragment shader I've used `gl_fragCoord.z` to see if that was correct and smaller triangles (further away) received a higher alpha than bigger ones (up close).

**What could be the cause of the weird drawing behaviour?**

Comment: Why would a triangle with z=1 not be drawn over a triangle with z=10? 1 **IS** less or equal 10.

Comment: I want a higher Z value to be on top, which should actually be `gl.GEQUAL` then, good point. The depth test still doesn't work on my updated `gl_Position`.

Comment: Please post a working snippet in the question. SO requires that: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself***.

Answer (score 1):

Depth in clipspace goes from -1 to 1. Depth written to the depth buffer goes from 0 to 1. You're clearing to 1. There is no depth value > 1 so the only things you should see drawn are at `gl_Position.z = 1`. Anything less than 1 will fail the test `gl.depthFunc(gl.GEQUAL);`. Anything > 1 will be clipped. Only 1 is both in the depth range and Greater than or Equal to 1

The example below draws smaller to larger rectangles with different z values. The red is standard `gl.depthFunc(gl.LESS)` with depth cleared to 1. The green is `gl.depthFunc(gl.GEQUAL)` with depth cleared to 0. The blue is `gl.depthFunc(gl.GEQUAL)` with depth cleared to 1. Notice blue only draws the single rectangle at `gl_Position.z = 1` because all other rectangles fail the test since they are at Z < 1.

```js
const m4 = twgl.m4;
const gl = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("webgl");
const vs = `
attribute vec4 position;
varying vec4 v_position;
uniform mat4 matrix;
void main() {
   gl_Position = matrix * position;
   v_position = abs(position);
}
`;
const fs = `
precision mediump float;
varying vec4 v_position;
uniform vec4 color;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(1. - v_position.xxx, 1) * color;
}
`;
// compiles shaders, links program, looks up attributes
const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);
// calls gl.createBuffer, gl.bindBindbuffer, gl.bufferData for each array
const z0To1BufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, {
  position: [ 
     ...makeQuad( .2, 0.00),
     ...makeQuad( .4,  .25),
     ...makeQuad( .6,  .50),
     ...makeQuad( .8,  .75),
     ...makeQuad(1.0, 1.00),
  ],
});
const z1To0BufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, {
  position: [ 
     ...makeQuad(.2, 1.00),
     ...makeQuad(.4,  .75),
     ...makeQuad(.6,  .50),
     ...makeQuad(.8,  .25),
     ...makeQuad(1., 0.00),
  ],
});

function makeQuad(xy, z) {
  return [
     -xy, -xy, z,
      xy, -xy, z,
     -xy,  xy, z,
     -xy,  xy, z,
      xy, -xy, z,
      xy,  xy, z,
  ];
}

gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);

gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

gl.clearDepth(1);
gl.clear(gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
gl.depthFunc(gl.LESS);
drawRects(-0.66, z0To1BufferInfo, [1, 0, 0, 1]);

gl.clearDepth(0);
gl.clear(gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
gl.depthFunc(gl.GEQUAL);
drawRects(0, z1To0BufferInfo, [0, 1, 0, 1]);

gl.clearDepth(1);
gl.clear(gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
gl.depthFunc(gl.GEQUAL);
drawRects(0.66, z1To0BufferInfo, [0, 0, 1, 1]);


function drawRects(xoffset, bufferInfo, color) {
  // calls gl.bindBuffer, gl.enableVertexAttribArray, gl.vertexAttribPointer
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
  
  let mat = m4.translation([xoffset, 0, 0]);
  mat = m4.scale(mat, [.3, .5, 1]);

  // calls gl.uniformXXX
  twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
    color: color,
    matrix: mat,
  });

  // calls gl.drawArrays or gl.drawElements
  twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/3.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
<pre>
red  : depthFunc: LESS,   clearDepth: 1
green: depthFunc: GEQUAL, clearDepth: 0
blue : depthFunc: GEQUAL, clearDepth: 1
</pre>
```

Comment: I've tested the different combinations and found depthFunc GEQUAL and clearDepth of 1 still working, this would mean that every triangle has a z-value of 1. The problem however is that all my triangles are drawn in a single drawArrays function and their Z is defined in the vertex shader. How would I get this to work? Currently with your solution the order still isn't right.

Comment: In my example the order is exactly what I expect it to be. I draw red with z = 0.1 -> 1.0 using `LESS` where 0.1 is small and 1.0 is large and I see that the large is drawn in behind the small, meaning the depth buffer worked as expected. Green is z = 1.0 to 0.1 where 1.0 is small and 0.1 is large. This time I'm using `GEQUAL`. Again since I draw 0.1 last and it's largest which shows it's working as expected. It doesn't overwrite the small thing at z = 1.0 since the depth buffer is working and was cleared to 0.

Comment: The last (blue) shows if the depth buffer is cleared to 1 then only things at 1.0 work (the first small rectangle). All the others don't work because they are less than 1.0 and the test is `GEQUAL`. In your example at a minimum you need to clear to 0 instead of 1 otherwise nothing except z = 1 can draw.

Comment: I understand how the z values affect the depth testing at this point, I've tried all different combinations but nothing seems to change the order of which they are drawn. `.drawArrays()` just draws every triangle over the next one, might this be because I have 1 draw call with different triangles in it instead of you having 3 different once?

Comment: No, I updated the sample to draw all the rectangles at once. I get the same result. You should post more code although you still have not acknowledged that your current code *CAN'T WORK* because it's clearing depth to 1 so the only value GEQUAL to 1 is 1. Anything more than that won't be drawn since it's clipped. Because of that if all your objects are at Z=1 then they are all GEQUAL so they will all be drawn in draw order. Otherwise are you drawing directly to the canvas or are you drawing to a framebuffer? If a framebuffer did you create a depth attachment?

Comment: Updated the code like you asked, I acknowledge that my old code with the 1 and gl.GEQUAL could not work, updated now.